# What is "Got it!" short for?

Tags: meaning, abbreviations

When you say "got it", what is it short for?

Is it for:

- I have it?
- I have got it?
- I have gotten it?
- I got it? *(Is this even valid?)*
- Something else?

Also: What is the tense of the verb?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It stands for :

> I have got it!

It means that you have *got* the meaning of something, understood something or obtained something

Comment: @Ham: Hm ok... what's the tense? Present perfect?

Comment: Yes, present perfect : "have"

Comment: +1. It can also be used for physical objects too, as well as understanding: "Have you found the torch yet? No, still searching... got it!"

Comment: @psmears, cool added that in...

Comment: I have always heard "I got it," when said from three American people I met.

Comment: What about the British people you never met? Jks. :-)